# vuex not returning object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I'm new to Vuex, and I'm running into problems when I use a variable as the parameter to retrieve card information from state.cards.

store.js:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        cards: []
    },
    getters: {
        getCard(state) {
            return id => state.cards.find(card => id === card.id);
        }
    }
});
```

card.vue:

```
computed: {
    card() {
        var id = this.$store.getters.getCard(this.$route.params.card);
        console.log(id);  // displays 88
        console.log(this.$store.getters.getCard(88));  // returns card info
        console.log(this.$store.getters.getCard(id));  // returns undefined
        return populateCard(
            this.$store.getters.getCard(id)
        );
    }    
}
```

If you look at the code above, the getter works when I pass the literal 88, but it does not work when I pass the variable id that is set to 88, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: You might double check your casting for a start. Is id 88 (an integer) or '88' (a string). My guess is you will need to ParseInt() your id.

Answer (score 0):

greendemiurge was correct. The router was returning a string, so wrapping the id in parseInt() fixed the issues.

```
computed: {
            card() {
                var id = this.$route.params.card;
                return populateCard(
                    this.$store.getters.getCard(parseInt(id, 10))
                );
            }
```